# ios6 - preserve data written by html5 storage in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I'd like to have my UIWebView persist data I write to it via html5 storage. The release notes from ios 6 make this sound possible by doing:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
    setBool:YES forKey:@"WebKitStoreWebDataForBackup"];
```

> "In iOS 6 and later, web data (SQL Web Storage and LocalStorage) from a UIWebView object can be stored in a directory that will be backed up. To enable backing up this data, set the WebKitStoreWebDataForBackup key to YES in your app’s user defaults. This should be done only if your app relies on web content data that cannot be reloaded. If your UIWebView object opens links to arbitrary web content, this key should be set to NO. Toggling the value of this key will not preserve existing web view data."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html

That's all we have to do - this is just a magic key? I'll just call it at app startup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is probably talking about backing up the device to iTunes or iCloud not about persisting data across app launches.